# Adding an AngularJS project to a Visual Studio 2012 solution

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2012

I would like to create a Visual Studio 2012 (Premium) solution, initially containing a project for an AngularJS client. Later on, at least one ASP.NET MVC 4 project will be added defining the server the AngularJS client talks to. We would like to keep these things in one solution.

The problem is that I cannot find a fitting project template (installed or online) or a way to manually define such a project. No matter which project template I choose there is always too much cruft being added, as all project templates are based on some programming language / environment irrelevant to the AngularJS project. I would be happy with a blank project template to which only the relevant html, js, css,... files would be added.

One could of course define the ASP.NET MVC 4 project and then add the client parts to some folders in that project, we had already done such things in the past, but things get very cluttered.

Do you know how to naturally define such a web client project in VS 2012 or if VS 2013 does handle this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We came up with the following solution: In Visual Studio, select "Add New Web Site" -> "ASP.NET Empty Web Site". This approach fits the bill since it does not add much to our AngularJS project and hosting the application is also taken care of.

Comment: How did you overcome the problem of defining routes for each environment like DEV PROD or even local?

Comment: I mean if you register a local endpoint like http://localhost/api/controller/action in production it will be http://website.com/api/controller/action..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a new ASP.NET Web API project. File - > New Project-> ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application . In the next screen, select "Web API". Since you are doing the client only using HTML,CSS and JS , your server side becomes a bunch of APIs for which you need to create a Web API project only and not a full MVC 4 app. Even Web API project also comes with some MVC4 files and folders, which you can remove easily.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this approach creates 454 files in 204 folders. I could now go on and delete most of it, but I hoped for a cleaner solution. If none can be found, I will stick with WebStorm and drop the idea of having everything in Visual Studio.

Comment: suits u!  what you can do is to use webstorm or any HTML editor for ur client app and create a new Web API project whenever ur backend work starts. Then also u need to deal with these 454 files!

Comment: Of course these files are needed for the Web API project, but I don't need any of them in the Web client project, that is what I meant. I did not want to make fun of your suggestion, in fact I tried something similar before, but it seems like a bad choice and it looks like we won't gain anything from sticking to Visual Studio in this case. Using a WebStorm project for the Web client seems to be a much better fit.